# Serialize the outcome of a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Code Snippet:

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("links.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

count = 0
for row in range(1, sh.nrows):
    val = sh.row_values(row)


    if (val[4]) != 2:
        print 'id',str(int(val[0])), 'value', str(int(val[1])) + "-" + str(int(val[2]))

    else:
        print 'id',str(int(val[0])), 'value', str(int(val[1])) + "-" + str(int(val[2]))
        print 'id',str(int(val[0])), 'value', str(int(val[2])) + "-" + str(int(val[1]))
```

links.xls

```
   id From To   Len  Permlanes
    1   1   7   350   9
    2   1   8   460   3
    3   1   3   490   2
    4   2   9   220   2
    5   2   7   540   1
    6   2   8   590   1
    7   3   6   250   1
    8   4   4   290   6
    9   4   9   570   1
    10  4   2   430   1
```

Output:

```
id 1 value 1-7
id 2 value 1-8
id 3 value 1-3
id 3 value 3-1
id 4 value 2-9
id 4 value 9-2
id 5 value 2-7
id 6 value 2-8
id 7 value 3-6
id 8 value 4-4
id 9 value 4-9
id 10 value 4-2
```

Intended Output:

```
id 1 value 1-7
id 2 value 1-8
id 3 value 1-3
id 4 value 3-1
id 5 value 2-9
id 6 value 9-2
id 7 value 2-7
id 8 value 2-8
id 9 value 3-6
id 10 value 4-4
id 11 value 4-9
id 12 value 4-2
```

The code above is a small description of a project I am working on. When the `permlanes fields is 2` in the excel file, the `value` is written twice in alternate pattern i.e. `1-3 and 3-1` however the `id` output is not as expected. Can someone help me with a way to adjust the code so that the `id output` is serial (just as in the intended output) rather than as it appears in the present output. My attempt to loop using  the index of a list of the excel file elements clearly did not work since there was no way of accessing the elements of the excel file.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm totally clueless how do you swap the values if the two lines are the same `print 'id',str(int(val[0])), 'value', str(int(val[1])) + "-" + str(int(val[2]))` and
`print 'id',str(int(val[0])), 'value', str(int(val[1])) + "-" + str(int(val[2]))`

Comment: @LuisMasuelli they don't print the same I have edited the lines thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have unused `count` variable so I used it to keep track of output indexes, increasing it everytime when we print a new id.

```
import xlrd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("links.xls")
sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

count = 1
for row in range(1, sh.nrows):
    val = sh.row_values(row)

    if (val[4]) != 2:
        print 'id',str(int(count)), 'value', str(int(val[1])) + "-" + str(int(val[2]))
    else:
        print 'id',str(int(count)), 'value', str(int(val[1])) + "-" + str(int(val[2]))
        count+=1
        print 'id',str(int(count)), 'value', str(int(val[2])) + "-" + str(int(val[1]))
    count+=1
```